# Porque o método .data() do jQuery não atualiza os dados no inspecionar elemento do navegador

Tags: javascript, jquery

Alguém sabe explicar porque o método [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data) do [jQuery](http://jquery.com) não atualiza (visualmente) os dados mostrados quando estamos usando o "inspecionar elemento" do navegador?

Os dados estão lá, pois é possível utiliza-los

```js
$(function() {
 var $results = $('#results'),
  $users = $('#users'),
  $displayData = $('#display-data');

 var users = ['Wagner', 'waghcwb'];

 // seta os dados
 $users.data('users', users);

 $displayData.click(function() {
  $results.fadeIn().find('.users').text( users.join(', ') );
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="users">inspecionar</div>
<button id="display-data">ver resultados</button>
<div id="results" style="display:none">usuários: <span class="users"></span></div>
```

Porém não é possível ver os dados no elemento em si ao inspecionar no navegador

[image: Sem dados no elemento]

Porém, veja que ao utilizar o método [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr) é possível ver os dados

```js
$(function() {
 var $results = $('#results'),
  $users = $('#users'),
  $displayData = $('#display-data');

 var users = ['Wagner', 'waghcwb'];

 // seta os dados
 $users.attr('data-users', users);

 $displayData.click(function() {
  $results.fadeIn().find('.users').text( users.join(', ') );
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="users">inspecionar</div>
<button id="display-data">ver resultados</button>
<div id="results" style="display:none">usuários: <span class="users"></span></div>
```

[image: Elemento com dados sendo mostrados]

@Edit:

Outro detalhe que esqueci de citar ao formular a pergunta, é que  também não é possível utilizar seletores jQuery para selecionar elementos com determinados dados no `data`, por exemplo:

```
$('.element[data-users]');
```

Isso não retorna o elemento com o atributo `data-users`...